# For loops aplied to add +1 to a variable in swift 3

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift3

I'm trying to add +1 to a variable called "turn" every time a press "enter" on the textfield. I have tried something, but it seems like is not working.

I want the value to start in -1, and then every time i return on the textfield, it takes a +1 value, and i want it to stop when turn = 1.

I want this because depending on the turn value, when i hit return on the textfield, something different should happen. And when turn = 1, it should stop increasing the value, because i olnu have 3 cases: turn -1; turn 0; turn 1

This is the code that i have in the textFieldShouldReturn

```
var turno = -1

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

for var i in -1 ..< 1 where i <= 1  {

    turno = i
    i += 1
}


if inputTextField.text != "" {


    if turn == -1 {
        let text = inputTextField.text
        if (text?.characters.count)! <= 2 {

            dosletras.text = text
            label.text = nil               
        }
    }

    if turno == 0 {
        label.text = inputTextField.text
    }

    if turno == 1 {

        //other things happen
    }

}

return true
```

}

I want to do somethig like that because i use that variable "turn" to do other things in my code. The problem that i'm having is with the labels that change the text depending on the turn value and the text of the inputTextfield

Any solutions?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you want it to run exactly 3 times? Why not just go from 0 to 2, inclusive? And there's no need for your `where` clause.

Comment: When turn is = -1,0 and 1, something happen in each case. I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it should be a while case statement. But how can i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're rather confused about how to increment a variable...

**Edited Answer:**

With your current code, the first thing you do when `textFieldShouldReturn()` is triggered is:

```
    for var i in -1 ..< 1 where i <= 1  {
        turno = i
        i += 1
    }
    // turno now equals 0
```

Regardless of the value of `turno` when you start that code, the result is zero. It will *never* be anything else. So, delete that code completely, and never try to use it again :)

Compare that to this code:

```
var turno = -1

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if inputTextField.text != "" {

        if turno == -1 {
            let text = inputTextField.text
            if (text?.characters.count)! <= 2 {
                dosletras.text = text
                label.text = nil
                turno = 0
            }
        }
        else if turno == 0 {
            label.text = inputTextField.text
            turno = 1
        }
        else if turno == 1 {
            //other things happen
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

Now, `turno` starts at `-1` ...

First time through, if `text` <= 2 characters, set the text of the labels and set `turno` to `0` ...

Next time through, if `turno` was set to `0` last time, set the label text and set `turno` to `1` ...

Every time through after that, `turno` will remain at `1`

---

**Original Answer:**

```
// initialize the variable "turn" to -1
var turn = -1

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    // increment turn by 1
    turn += 1

    // if turn is now > 1, return false
    if turn > 1 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

So, `turn` starts at `-1`...

The first time `textFieldShouldReturn` is called, `turn` will be incremented by `1` and will now equal `0`, so the func returns `true`.

The next time `textFieldShouldReturn` is called, `turn` will be incremented by `1` and will now equal `1`, so again the func returns `true`.

The third time `textFieldShouldReturn` is called, `turn` will be incremented by `1` and will now equal `2` (which is greater than 1), so the func returns `false`.

Comment: I have updated my code, so you can see the problems that i'm having